# HTML5 Audio Capture - How to truncate recorded audio

Tags: javascript, html, audio, webrtc

I am developing a feature to capture audio inside an HTML5 application from a microphone/headset. Using MediaStreamRecorder which works quite nice and I am able to capture all audio. However during playback of the recorded audio I noticed the mouse click which comes from user clicking on the Stop recording button on the scream is also captured. I would like to get rid of it somehow. One idea was to drop the last 0.5-1 sec from the recording but I am not entirely sure how to implement this. Maybe there are some other more appropriate approaches to this as well...

Any suggestions with code samples from the experts would be great.

Comment: you can slice the big sample array before you turn it into a WAV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MediaStreamRecorder.js does not offer flexibility to trim the recording at either end and produces a ready to use WAV encoded byte stream to the client application. Because the byte stream is already WAV encoded, it is very difficult to apply trimming at that time. Hovever, a small change in the core MediaStreamEncoder can provide this functionality in a configurable way i.e. as client application sees it fit.

trimFromFront and trimFromEnd properties have to be added to Recorder which can then be used just before WAV encoding takes place.

The final buffer with collected samples is managed in Float32Array. We know the sample rate which usually is 44100 bps. We can apply this to extract a subarray from the final buffer truncating the portion of interest.

```
interleaved = interleaved.subarray(trimFromFront * sampleRate, interleaved.length - trimFrontEnd * sampleRate)
```

This gives us flexibility to truncate a fraction of a second as well.

So if I want to truncate 2 sec from front and 5 sec from end I would do

```
trimFromFront = 2;
trimFromEnd = 5;
```

That is all. The final WAV encoded byte stream comes up clean.

Answer (score 0):

I can see three solutions for your problem:

- Easy one, send it to server, clip using `ffmpeg` n stuff. con: server gets involved.
- like dandavis said in comment, Use [RecorderJS](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs), only while forming the final wav file from array, ignore last few entries. con: tedious, and wav files can be huge( bec it is uncompressed)
- do the editing client side, pipe the recorded video to audio element(, mute it) and you create a stream using [`mozCaptureStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) and record it, and use set timeout to stop it .5 seconds before actual finish. con: like you would have guessed, works only in firefox for now